# St_Transform() - Postgis function Error: column "geom" does not exist

Tags: postgis, polygon

I am trying to add a new column in the planet_osm_polygon table in order to have a new column with the areas of all the polygons in the database. These are the commands I have used:

```
psql -U postgres -d gis -c "alter table planet_osm_polygon add column area real"

psql -U postgres -d gis -c "update planet_osm_polygon set area=st_area(st_transform(geom, 2154))
```

How am I supposed to use `ST_Transform()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geometry column is called `way` by default, not `geom`